# Tell webpack that certain node_module is sideEffect free

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I'm using UI library that does not support `sideEffects:false` yet. And version I'm using is not already maintained, so they won't do patch release...

However I've manually tested and when `sideEffects:false` was added to the library it works perfectly fine and bundle size got decreased significantly (as I'm using only subset of UI components).

Is there a way to tell Webpack 4 that a particular `node_module` is side effect free?